# MySQL Load data infile UTF8 encoding

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to insert data from a utf8 encoded text file into a utf8 encoded mysql database.

A line in the textfile I am trying to insert looks like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Canada_(New_France)> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Canada_(1534–1763)> .
```

To load the file into the database I use this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/file'
INTO TABLE table_name
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(s, @p, o)
COMMIT;
```

The create table command looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `article_categories3` (`s` varchar(511) NOT NULL, `o` varchar(511) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Unfortunately the resulting entry in the database looks like this:

```
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Canada_(New_France)>       | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Canada_(1534û1763)> |
```

'-' is getting replaced by 'û'.
The same happens for other special characters, like 'ï' gets replaced by '´'.

mysql shows these charsets:

```
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
character_set_results: latin1
```

changing client and connection charset and character_set_results to `utf8` with the command `\C utf8` results in:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Canada_(1534ÔÇô1763)>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:O├»l_languages>
```

changing them to `cp850` results in:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Canada_(1534?1763)>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Oïl_languages>
```

So with this setting 'ï' is shown correct.

I also tried writing a little java program, which inserts the lines from the file into the database, but I encounter the same result with this approach.

But if I manually type an insert command into the mysql-console, it will get inserted correct:

```
 INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Canada_(New_France)>', '<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Canada_(1534–1763)>');
```

The Hex codes of the entries are:

```
3C687474703A2F2F646270656469612E6F72672F7265736F757263652F43617465676F72793A486973746F72795F6F665F43616E6164615F2831353334E2809331373633293E
```

(endash here `E28093`)

and

```
3C687474703A2F2F646270656469612E6F72672F7265736F757263652F43617465676F72793A4FC3AF6C5F6C616E6775616765733E
```

I checked the encoding of the text file like this:

```
file -i test.ttl
test.ttl: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Do you have an idea, what else i could try to load the file into the database with the correct encoding?

Comment: Get the `HEX()` of that column -- `û` is hex `C3BB`; endash and emdash are `E28093` and `E28094` in utf8.  Something else is going on.  Also, `ï` and `´` have not direct mapping.  (So, it is not obvious what is going on; the `HEX` should help.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the character set `cp850` somewhere in the flow of data.

Please provide

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
- The connection parameters when connecting to MySQL.

Also verify that the incoming data is actually encoded `UTF-8`.

Get the `HEX()` of that column -- `û` is hex `C3BB`; endash and emdash are `E28093` and `E28094` in utf8.  Something else is going on.

**More**

*All three* of these need to be set the same:  `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection`, and `character_set_results`.

Comment: I added the information to my question. With setting the client-connection to `cp850` `ï` is shown correct but `-` is still shown wrong.

Comment: `character_set_results`, too.  It was coincidence that one worked and one failed.  This is because cp850 has some overlap with latin1.

Comment: `character_set_results` is set to `latin1`. By changing the connection charset with the command `\C utf8` it also changes to `utf8`.

Comment: A glimpse into the future:  MySQL 8.0 defaults to `utf8mb4` all the way.  (latin1 is primarily for legacy MySQL data; cp850 and dozens of other encodings are only for reading other legacy data -- with the intent of quickly moving to UTF-8.)